# Подключение к БД не на своем сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, господа.

Есть сайт, в админке которого спокойно работаю с БД.  Но возникла необходимость подключения к БД (нескольким) не на этом хостинге. Выполнять с запросы, и т.п. Как это делать?

На ум пришло не самое умное решение: iframe внутри своей CMS, и уже из iframe своя CMS. Второй вариант, что-то сделать с подключением к БД, вместо localhost, что-то прописать волшебное. Но, в любом случае, это догадки. Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: Задайте вопрос хостеру:
>Можно ли получить доступ к базе данных с другого сервера?

Ответ может знать только хостер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подключения к удаленной БД вместо localhost пишите IP сервера базы данных и все. Но перед этим проверьте, пользователю от имени которого вы подключаетесь к базе должно быть разрешено удаленное подключение

Comment: ок. понял.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача заключается, как я понял, в подключение к MySql серверу извне. Это, во-первых, позволяют не все хостеры в целях безопасности, как они обычно утверждают. Так что, сперва поговорите с членами службы поддержки и разузнайте что, да как. Если же хостер позволяет подключение извне, то вам надо указать список хостов( пользовательские ip ), с которых возможно подключение. Ну, естественно, так как разрешать каждый по отдельности хост - полный бред, просто можно указать, что доступ разрешен всем и каждому( это можно сделать, введя вместо хоста символ "%"( так обычно ) в панели управления ).

Comment: допустим если можно подключиться к БД, на определенном хостинге из вне с любого компьютера. допустим. в место localhost, что должно быть прописано что?

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost','login','pass');

Comment: external ip adress или домен , где установлен сервер базы данных.

Comment: ок. понял.